# How can I add again a programmatically created linearlayout to another linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a child linearlayout created programmatically and added on a parent linearlayour programmatically.

`parentlayout.addView(childlayout)`

But, the I want to add again the child layout to another linearlayout, it returns an error, is it possible? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating LinearLayout Programmatically/Dynamically with Multiple Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283723/creating-linearlayout-programmatically-dynamically-with-multiple-views)

Comment: No, you need to either remove it's parent or create another instance and add that to the other parent LL

Comment: have solved this ? or there is still some issue left ?

Answer (score 1):

Create another `instance` of the same `class`, and set the same `properties`. I mean Inflate your `View` again if needed. Because A single `View` cannot be a child of two `ViewGroup` parents.

Answer (score 1):

Each view can have only one parent possible.
So you can not add same child to another linear layout.
What you can do is make another instance, apply same properties which you given to previous child. and then add this instance to the parent view.