# Dynamically Created Layout not Showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've looked at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283723/creating-linearlayout-programmatically-dynamically-with-multiple-views), however I still cannot find out what I'm doing wrong. There are no errors in Logcat and there definitely is data being passed to it to be made. Here's my setup:

This is all taking place below manually placed elements that I have placed in Android Studio. I have a ScrollView. Inside that ScrollView, I have a LinearLayout, `parentLayout`, that get's passed to this class. This method is supposed to add another Horizontal LinearLayout, `layout`, `parentLayout`. Then it is supposed to add a TextView, `titleDisplay`,  and two Buttons to `layout`. So far I have only programmed just `layout` and `titleDisplay`. I tested it, and nothing was added. So before I program the other two buttons, I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Here's the Java Code:

```
public class FollowupOption {

private String displayName;
private JSONObject jsonInformation;
private Context context;
private LinearLayout parentLayout;

private LinearLayout layout;
private TextView titleDisplay;
private Button deleteButton, editButton;

public FollowupOption(String displayName, JSONObject jsonInformation,
                      Context context, LinearLayout parentLayout){
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.jsonInformation = jsonInformation;
    this.context = context;
    this.parentLayout = parentLayout;
    buildLayout();
}

private void buildLayout(){
    //Horizontal Linear Layout to hold everything
    this.layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    this.layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    this.layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    this.parentLayout.addView(this.layout);
    //Text View Displaying title of followup option.
    this.titleDisplay = new TextView(context);
    try {
        this.titleDisplay.setText(this.jsonInformation.getJSONObject("list").getString("title"));
    } catch(JSONException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    this.titleDisplay.setTextColor(0x8f142a); //Black
    this.titleDisplay.setTextSize(18);
    this.titleDisplay.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    this.layout.addView(this.titleDisplay);
}
}
```

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.22"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/followup_text"
                android:textColor="@color/myRed"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/followup_add_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="@string/plus"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="279dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/followup_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/followup_new_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/new_followup_text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

If someone could let me know what I am doing wrong or a good way to debug something like this, that would be appreciated.

Comment: The XML would help ensure this isn't a layout issue

Comment: I updated the question with the XML @Milk

Comment: Are you seeing a stack trace? Can you try replacing `this.titleDisplay.setText(...)` with some static text?

Comment: LogCat doesn't show any errors. I just tried you suggestion about static text, and still nothing appears. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding `this.layout` view to some view?

**UPD:** The problem is with your text color. Consider using the Color class to get color from its hex value or constants from that class.

Comment: Doesn't this line `this.parentLayout.addView(this.layout);` do that?

Comment: What is `this.parentLayout`? I may be that the `parentLayout` is not added to the view.

Comment: Ye, it does. Can you provide the full code of this class? Have no idea why this is not working

Comment: @Milk As I stated in the question, `parentLayout` is a LinearLayout already in the View passed to this class.

Comment: @PotapovAnton Just did. There's not much else, though. Just a constructor.

Comment: The color thing was the problem. I used the Color class. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Does your XML view (without the addition of the dynamic layout) take up the entire screen?

The new `LinearLayout` view will be added below the button. If the button is at the bottom of the screen, the layout will be added off the screen and therefore not visible.

You should add your new layout to the scroll view instead.

Comment: I beleive, views are adding in scrollview in the middle of the screen

Comment: Well, I thought that the new LinearLayout would be added to `parentLayout` (which is followup_parent in the xml). I'll try your suggestion about adding it just to the ScrollView.

Comment: Can you try hard coding some views in the `parentView` in the XML to see if it's an issue adding the view dynamically, or an issue with the layout?

Comment: Just did that, and it works fine in there. Just can't get it to make it dynamically.