# Create Layout Resource Programmatically Kotlin Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

I'm having problems trying to make this Layout totally programmatically, every time the process run end without success and the app crashes.

The Part of XML im trying to create programmatically is it :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idImagenPlay0"
            android:layout_width="62dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_play" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idNombre0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idInfo0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Title" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idImagenShare0"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to recreate it with the following kotlin code:

```
fun createXmlElement(title:String,description:String){
    val parent = LinearLayout(this)
    parent.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    parent.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL

    //children of parent linearlayout
    val iv = ImageView(this)
    val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lp.setMargins(0, 11, 7, 0)
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp)
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play)
    iv.getLayoutParams().height = 40;
    iv.getLayoutParams().width = 46;

    parent.addView(iv); // lo agregamos al layout

    val relativeP = RelativeLayout(this)
    relativeP.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

    val linearCH = LinearLayout(this)
    linearCH.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    // TextView1
    val tv1 = TextView(this)
    val lptv1 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lptv1.setMargins(0, 7, 0, 0)

    tv1.setLayoutParams(lptv1)
    tv1.setText(title) // nombre de la musica
    tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,25F)
    tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    // TextView2
    val tv2 = TextView(this)
    val lptv2 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lptv2.setMargins(0, 11, 7, 0)

    tv2.setLayoutParams(lptv1)
    tv2.setText(description) // Descripcion de la musica
    tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25F)
    tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    linearCH.addView(tv1)
    linearCH.addView(tv2)

    relativeP.addView(linearCH)

    // last ImageView
    val iv2 = ImageView(this)
    val lpiv2 = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lpiv2.setMargins(0, 11, 7, 0)
    lpiv2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT)
    iv2.setLayoutParams(lpiv2)
    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_share)
    iv2.getLayoutParams().height = 40;
    iv2.getLayoutParams().width = 46;


    parent.addView(iv)
    parent.addView(relativeP)
    parent.addView(iv2)


}
```

This is the error I'm getting in logcat

```
04-27 10:51:01.224 6973-6973/com.klystru.app.appE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.klystru.app.app, PID: 6973
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.klystru.app.app/com.klystru.app.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4453)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4281)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4222)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4195)
    at com.klystru.app.app.MainActivity.createXmlElement(MainActivity.kt:284)
    at com.klystru.app.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:121)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

I still research what it can be, I'm suspecting it may be wrong LayoutParams, but it's not really clear about how to set up correctly those resources programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

PD: If I found something I will update.

Any help will be really welcome!

UPDATE 1.0:

Ok following the logcat I have to call `removeView` in child's parent, but I don't know exactly where. I am looking for that.

Comment: Maybe that would be helpful to post the crash you're getting as well?

Comment: Thank you!, I forget to check the logcats!! Look like i have to call removeView() first anywhere....

Comment: Logcat states the error lies into the function `createMusicElement()`, and not in the `createXmlElement()` that you pasted (unless they are indeed the same, just renamed when pasted here)

Comment: Yeah, they are the same, i just renamed it. Done...

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're skipping the layout inflater?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Because im new to kotlin and android layout? Just maybe...

Comment: No see that makes me double not understand why you are writing it from code. You're skipping the AppCompatLayoutInflater this way. That's why people use the XML layout.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i may be new to android layout, but im not nwe to kotlin and sqlite, and i need sqlite functionality which will require a constantly changing layout, and there is where creating layout from code help a lot!

Comment: No, if you need "constantly changing layout", then you need a RecyclerView.

Comment: Ok, my actual approach is working fine but implementing RecyclerView i think is better than my actual code.... I will give a check, thank you for the advise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok the solution is as following:

Just need to add removeAllView on all parents before adding the childs

```
protected fun createXmlElement(title:String,description:String){
    val parent = LinearLayout(this)
    parent.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    parent.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL



    //children of parent linearlayout
    val iv = ImageView(this)
    val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lp.setMargins(0, 11, 7, 0)
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp)
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play)
    iv.getLayoutParams().height = 40
    iv.getLayoutParams().width = 46


    parent.addView(iv); // lo agregamos al layout

    val relativeP = RelativeLayout(this)
    relativeP.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

    val linearCH = LinearLayout(this)
    linearCH.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    // TextView1
    val tv1 = TextView(this)
    val lptv1 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lptv1.setMargins(0, 7, 0, 0)

    tv1.setLayoutParams(lptv1)
    tv1.setText(title) // title
    tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,25F)
    tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)

    // TextView2
    val tv2 = TextView(this)
    val lptv2 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lptv2.setMargins(0, 11, 7, 0)

    tv2.setLayoutParams(lptv1)
    tv2.setText(description) // description
    tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25F)
    tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)

    linearCH.removeAllViews()
    linearCH.addView(tv1)
    linearCH.addView(tv2)

    relativeP.removeAllViews()
    relativeP.addView(linearCH)

    // last ImageView
    val iv2 = ImageView(this)
    val lpiv2 = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lpiv2.setMargins(0, 11, 7, 0)
    lpiv2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT)
    iv2.setLayoutParams(lpiv2)
    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_share)
    iv2.getLayoutParams().height = 40
    iv2.getLayoutParams().width = 46


    parent.removeAllViews()
    parent.addView(iv)
    parent.addView(relativeP)
    parent.addView(iv2)

    val finalParent = this.findViewById(R.id.contenedor) as ViewGroup

    finalParent.addView(parent)
}
```

Thanks NSion, the error on logcat point to me the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from the answer above.
This is my helper function.

In OnViewCreated

```
val titleCard = createNumberCard()
        val verse1Card:CardView = createVerseCard()

        detailLinearLayout.addView(titleCard, 0)
        detailLinearLayout.addView(verse1Card, 1)
```

```
private fun createVerseCard(): CardView {
        //verseCard
        val verseCard = CardView(requireActivity())
        verseCard.setId(View.generateViewId())

        val verseCardLayout = ConstraintLayout(activity)
        verseCardLayout.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )

        verseCard.addView(verseCardLayout)

        val set = ConstraintSet()

        val verseView = TextView(activity)
        verseView.text = "Verse 1"
        verseView.setId(View.generateViewId())

        verseCardLayout.addView(verseView, 0)

        set.clone(verseCardLayout)

        set.connect(
            verseView.getId(),
            ConstraintSet.TOP,
            verseCardLayout.getId(),
            ConstraintSet.TOP,
            0
        )

        set.applyTo(verseCardLayout)
        return verseCard
    }
```

Im using these in a fragment.