# How to display another textview in this code?

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager

Can you explain How to display another textview in this code? I'm using viewpager so i just print only one textview i want one more textview. please anybody can you help me. 
thanks in advance.

**this is my code**

**This is my Mainactivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the GridView
        setTitle("GridView");
        // Get the view from grid_view.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

        // Set the images from ImageAdapter.java to GridView
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
         //gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));  //commented line 05052018 
        gridview.setAdapter(new ChangesofAdapter(this)); //new line 05052018
        // Listening to GridView item click
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // Launch ImageViewPager.java on selecting GridView Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageViewPager.class);

                // Show a simple toast message for the item position
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Send the click position to ImageViewPager.java using intent
                i.putExtra("id", position);

                // Start ImageViewPager
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**this is my gridview class -> ChangesofAdapter.class**

```
public class ChangesofAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public ChangesofAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return getDataContacts().length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return getDataContacts()[position];
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
            imageView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            imageView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT); // new line 05052018
            imageView.setTextSize(30);
        } else {
            imageView = (TextView) convertView;
        }
        String abc =getDataContacts()[position];
        imageView.setText(abc); // new line 05052018
        return imageView;
    }
    public String[] getContacts(){
        DBUtils utils = new DBUtils(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        new DBUtils((mContext.getApplicationContext()));
        try {
            DBUtils.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(" Create Db "+e.toString(),"===");
        }
        DBUtils.openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = utils.getResult("select * from Cflviewpagerdata order by title");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("view")));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        DBUtils.closeDataBase();
        return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
    }
    public String[] getDataContacts(){
        DBUtils utils = new DBUtils(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        new DBUtils((mContext.getApplicationContext()));
        try {
            DBUtils.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(" Create Db "+e.toString(),"===");
        }
        DBUtils.openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = utils.getResult("select * from Cflviewpagerdata order by title");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        DBUtils.closeDataBase();
        return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
    }
}
```

This code is represents while click grid view items this page will call this page is have viewpager of grid view items
**this class is viewpager -> ImageViewpager.class**

```
    public class ImageViewPager extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    // Declare Variable
    int position;
    Bundle img = new Bundle();
    ViewPager vp;
    private TextToSpeech mTts;
    List<TextView> images;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the ViewPager
        setTitle("ViewPager");
        // Get the view from view_pager.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
        Intent p = getIntent();
        position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");  
        ChangesofAdapter imageAdapter = new ChangesofAdapter(this); //new line 05052018
        images = new ArrayList<TextView>(); //new line 05052018

        // Retrieve all the images
        for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            TextView imageView = new TextView(this); //new line 05052018
            String abc = imageAdapter.getContacts()[i];
            imageView.setText(imageAdapter.getContacts()[i]);  //new line 05052018
            imageView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            imageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);//new line 05052018
            img.putString("CURRENT_POSITION", abc);
            images.add(imageView);
        }
        vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);         //new line 06052018
        vp.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(images));    //new line 06052018
        vp.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        vp.setCurrentItem(position);                    //new line 06052018
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private List<TextView> images;  
        public ViewPagerAdapter(List<TextView> images) {
            this.images = images;
        }   
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {
            final TextView imageView = images.get(position);                              //commented line on date 06052018
            container.addView(imageView);
            imageView.setTextSize(120);
            vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                 int  currentposition = pos;
                 mTts.speak(images.get(currentposition).getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {                
                }
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                }
            });     
            return imageView;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView(images.get(position));
        }   
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return images.size();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return view == o;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if (mTts != null) {
            mTts.shutdown();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //Close the Text to Speech Library
        if(mTts != null) {
            mTts.stop();
            mTts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public void onInit(int arg0) {
        if(arg0 == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            mTts.speak(images.get(position).getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my application look**

This is my Gridview look and while click item number seven this item will open viewpager that is second look.

[image]

This is my viewpager look in this look i want more textview.

how to display another textview below item(seven) or above item(seven)

[image]

This is my code can any one help me. i'm new one of Android programmer learner.

Please........

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 optional way

like i see you use one of them so you can continue with it which is

**FIRST WAY : Programmatically**

```
imageView = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        imageView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT); // new line 05052018
        imageView.setTextSize(30);
```

so you can add more ANYOBJECT with it here but put them into container

check this out

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26133978/6998825

**SEC WAY : MODULE AND REFF**

this way you will create XML layout and inflate it in your baseadapter so you can use it's element

row_module.xml FOR EX

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/table_IMG"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/table_num"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/table_ID"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

in your adapter something like this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_model, null);

    TextView TV_ID = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.table_ID); // ID
    ImageView bgImg =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.table_IMG); // IMG
    TextView TV_details = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.table_num); // details

    HashMap<String, String> arraylist_type = new HashMap<String, String>();
    arraylist_type = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    TV_ID.setText(arraylist_type.get("ID"));

    Glide.with(activity).load(arraylist_type.get("IMG")).into(bgImg);

    TV_details.setText(arraylist_type.get("details"));

    return vi;
}
```