# How to add to linear layout in java (without XML)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to add a line of texts inside linear layout(Vertical)

and I want to add them in function in java

How to do this?

Comment: add `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` programmatically?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283723/creating-linearlayout-programmatically-dynamically-with-multiple-views

Answer (score 0):

To add dynamically in Java write like this :
LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this) ;

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//add layout params
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//add TextView inside the vertical LinearLayout
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(16); //set the text size here
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the text color here
textView.setText("Texts"); // set the text here
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.BOLD); // set the text style here
linearLayout.addView(textView, p); // add the TextView to the LinearLayout
```

You can add any views inside the `LinearLayout` as much as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use addView :

```
LinearLayout layoutCard  = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
text.setText("hello");
layoutCard.addView(text);
```