# Why My programatically created LinearLayouts not shown

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a LinearLayout programmatically but for some reason it is not shown and I have no errors in Logcat or Run terminals.

Here is my Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String [] arr = {"1","2","3"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        LinearLayout child;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            child = new LinearLayout(this);
            child.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            child.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            parent.addView(child);
        }

    }
}
```

and my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have 3 LinearLayouts created according to the array length as I will pass some TextViews to them later

I tried to follow the answer I found [Creating LinearLayout Programmatically/Dynamically with Multiple Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283723/creating-linearlayout-programmatically-dynamically-with-multiple-views) but still cannot see the LinearLayouts created on the simulator.

Here is how it shows:
[Simulator Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y0ek.png)

I'm unsure what am I doing wrong?

Thank you for the hints and help.

Comment: Maybe there is code that you are not showing, but your linear layouts don't have any content so the height is zero. You can test this easily by replacing `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` with a specific height, say,  "200".

Comment: True, that was my problem, thank you for the hint.
I used 
`LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`
then 
` lp.height = 150`
and this fixed my issue

Comment: Android Studio's Layout Inspector is a good tool to debug layout problems like this - for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Used the below and this fixed the issue:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.height = 150;
```

Comment: The `WRAP_CONTENT` you're passing in to the constructor is in fact the height, so you are creating it with one value and then overriding it straight away with a different one. It's fine if you're just doing this so you can see them now, but you probably want to stick with `WRAP_CONTENT` when you add the subview. You might also want to consider what happens when you have more than 3 items in the array — you may need to wrap `rootLayout` in a `ScrollView` or, if there are likely to be a lot of elements, replace the whole thing with a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.